# Seeing the history of edits to one's own post

Tags: support, revisions-list

If I make a post and I make edits to it and perhaps others make edits to it as well, then, can I see the list of all edits (is this information made permanent in the SE database), or does subtituting one post with a newer one overwrite the old information completely thus losing it?

So, to summarize

1. If a post made by me has edited 5 times, can I see post versions 1, 2, 3, and 4 perhaps by clicking on the UI or just post 5.
2. How many points would I need to see this info?

Thanks.